# flowplayer HTML5 pre-roll with hls

Tags: javascript, html, flowplayer, http-live-streaming

How can I use flowplayer HTML5 with DFP ? I tried this link below, but this dosen't work with HLS...

http://demos.flowplayer.org/v5/ads/dfp.html

Comment: http://demos.flowplayer.org/basics/hls.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this plugin below to create this task:

http://demos.flowplayer.org/ads/vast.html